# Ubuntu 19.10 + SoundBlaster X Katana setup

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I am looking for help and tips how to set up Sound Blaster X Katana soundbar (https://us.creative.com/p/speakers/sound-blasterx-katana) in Ubuntu 19.10. Only thing i can do atm is get 2.0 to work with it, and its little bugged in-games as-well (in-game character voice are muted or not working).

I have checked muted channels, tried to edit pulse settings in daemon.conf with no luck. I have just moves from windows world to Linux and i am struggling to make sound hardware to work well.

description: Audio device
                   product: Sound BlasterX Katana
                   vendor: Creative Technology Ltd
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 2.00
                   capabilities: usb-1.10 audio-control
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s

I checked here https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Matrix:Vendor-Creative_Labs and found no info about the soundbar, i am guessing it is not supported? Have anyone gotten anywhere with the soundbar or creative is lost cause in Linux world?

EDIT:

```
lsusb -v output

Bus 001 Device 014: ID 041e:3247 Creative Technology, Ltd Sound BlasterX Katana

Device Descriptor:
bLength                18
bDescriptorType         1
bcdUSB               1.10
bDeviceClass            0 
bDeviceSubClass         0 
bDeviceProtocol         0 
bMaxPacketSize0        64
idVendor           0x041e Creative Technology, Ltd
idProduct          0x3247 
bcdDevice            2.00
iManufacturer           1 Creative Technology Ltd
iProduct                2 Sound BlasterX Katana
bNumConfigurations      1
Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x01ad
    bNumInterfaces          5
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength       0x00c4
        bInCollection           2
        baInterfaceNr(0)        1
        baInterfaceNr(1)        2
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            17
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            18
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               3 External Mic
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            20
        wTerminalType      0x0602 Digital Audio Interface
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               8 What U Hear
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            19
        wTerminalType      0x0603 Line Connector
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               5 Line-In
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            32
        wTerminalType      0x0605 SPDIF interface
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               4 SPDIF In
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            33
        wTerminalType      0x0503 Down Line Phone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               6 Bluetooth/USB Flash
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            21
        wTerminalType      0x0301 Speaker
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               1
        iTerminal               7 Speakers
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            22
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID              11
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 1
        bSourceID              10
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls(0)       0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls(1)       0x02
          Volume Control
        bmaControls(2)       0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID              18
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls(0)       0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls(1)       0x02
          Volume Control
        bmaControls(2)       0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        bSourceID              20
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls(0)       0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls(1)       0x02
          Volume Control
        bmaControls(2)       0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 8
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (SELECTOR_UNIT)
        bUnitID                11
        bNrInPins               2
        baSourceID(0)           2
        baSourceID(1)           4
        iSelector               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 7
        bSourceID              18
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls(0)       0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls(1)       0x02
          Volume Control
        bmaControls(2)       0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 6
        bSourceID              19
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls(0)       0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls(1)       0x02
          Volume Control
        bmaControls(2)       0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 8
        bSourceID              32
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls(0)       0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls(1)       0x02
          Volume Control
        bmaControls(2)       0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 9
        bSourceID              33
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls(0)       0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls(1)       0x02
          Volume Control
        bmaControls(2)       0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      4 (MIXER_UNIT)
        bUnitID                10
        bNrInPins               5
        baSourceID(0)          17
        baSourceID(1)           6
        baSourceID(2)           7
        baSourceID(3)           8
        baSourceID(4)           9
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        bmControls(0)        0x00
        iMixer                  0 
      Warning: Junk at end of descriptor (2 bytes):
        00 00 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink          17
        bDelay                  0 frames
        wFormatTag         0x0001 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           3
        bBitResolution         24
        bSamFreqType            1 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        48000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x012c  1x 300 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress         129
        AudioStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay         0x0000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0003  1x 3 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                4
        bSynchAddress           0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink          17
        bDelay                  0 frames
        wFormatTag         0x0001 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           3
        bBitResolution         24
        bSamFreqType            1 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        96000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x024c  1x 588 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress         129
        AudioStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay         0x0000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0003  1x 3 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                4
        bSynchAddress           0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink          22
        bDelay                  1 frames
        wFormatTag         0x0001 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           3
        bBitResolution         24
        bSamFreqType            1 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        48000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x012c  1x 300 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay         0x0000
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      80
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               2
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        4
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      29
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               2
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0xa600
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: Please show the output of `lsusb -v` for this device.

Comment: Output added to main body, hope it helps.

Comment: This is a two-channel device; any 5.1 or 7.1 processing is virtual, i.e., fake. Does `aplay something.wav` work well?

Comment: Downloaded random .wav file, used aplay command, got static.

Playing WAVE 'something.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo

I am guessing that virtual 5.1/7.1 is no go in linux or there is just no software like creative has for mac/win to emulate it?